# How can I specify a command-line command with options as an equalprg?

Tags: indentation, filetype-javascript

I am trying to set up the Node.js version of [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) as an `equalprg` command when I am editing a JavaScript file, so that the Vim `=` indent commands reflow my JavaScript at the same time.

Initially, I tried this:

```
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal equalprg=js-beautify -f -
```

(the `-f -` is necessary because js-beautify otherwise doesn't read from stdin).

However, that fails with an error like this when I open a JavaScript file:

```
Error detected while processing FileType Auto commands for "javascript":
E518: Unknown option: -f
```

So then I tried adding surrounding quotes:

```
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal equalprg="js-beautify -f -"
```

That seems to work (JavaScript files open without error), but then <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (or any other <kbd>=</kbd> command) seems to work in exactly the same way as the standard vim behaviour, and it appears it's not set up correctly - if I type `:set equalprg`, I see:

```
equalprg=
```

If I remove the `-f -`, the `equalprg` is set, but it doesn't work, because js-beautify tries to read from a file:

```
Must define at least one file.
Run `js-beautify -h` for help.
```

How can pass these command-line options into js-beautify as part of setting equalprg?

Note I am aware that I could use the js-beautify vim plugin, but I'm trying not to overwhelm my vim setup with plugins, and instead setup the standard vim `=` keymapping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close, but you have to use single quotes instead of double quotes, because Vim interprets `"` as a comment in this context:

```
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal equalprg='js-beautify -f -'
```

Or just escape the spaces:

```
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal equalprg=js-beautify\ -f\ -
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! Is there any explanation as to why viml/vimscript expects `\` here and not a quoted string instead? Seems unusual to me.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier It looks like Vim is interpreting `"` as a comment in this context, so the command you're really running is `setlocal equalprg=`.

Comment: In Vim 8.1, the single quote solution will also fail with the E518 error. Has something in Vim changed since you wrote your answer?